# Create global caching in class library at .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .net core 2.0 Web Api project.I have 10 web Api's and one class library project. I want to cache some data. So I create `CacheHelper.cs` in class library. And I inject to `Startup.cs` in web api projects. I want to call SetCommonCacheItems when webapi project start and getting anywhere in my controller. But when I call GetCities function, return null. What can be problem?

CacheHelper.cs (in class library project)

```
public class CacheHelper : ICacheHelper
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    public CacheHelper(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void SetCommonCacheItems()
    {
        var cities= unitOfWork.CityRepo.GetAll();
        cache.Set("city", cities);
    }

    public string GetCities()
    {
        string obj;
        cache.TryGetValue<string>("city", out obj);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs  (in Web API project)

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddScoped<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddScoped<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

Comment: Please stop using .NET Core 2.0. It has known security issues that will not be fixed. For example, CVE-2018-8292: .NET Core Information Disclosure Vulnerability. I would suggest upgrading to 2.1 ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using 2.1. I wrote only for question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `services.AddMemoryCache();` register `MemoryCache` like this `services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>());`, it means that cache is in singleton scope and will not be disposed after request is finished.

But in `CacheHelper` you have created `MemoryCache` via constructor, and, as soon as `CacheHelper` is disposed after request is finished, your cache will be lost.

To change this behavior, your have 2 options:

- Add 'IMemoryCache' dependency into `CacheHelper`: `public CacheHelper(IMemoryCache cache, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {}`
- Made `CacheHelper` to be singleton: `services.AddScoped<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();`

Comment: Thanks @AxeUser. I edited my code like `services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>());` . And it worked. But for every request it goes to `CacheHelper`. But I want only when project starting and then for every 8 hour. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using your cache as a "scoped" service which means for every request the framework will create a new cache object, and the one you set at the app start will be lost.

Try this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();
```

**Important:** This will break your unit of work as it will be a singleton as well within your cache.

I recommend to not use the unit of work inside the cache, instead just pass the results from your repo to your SetCommonCacheItems() as an argument.

**Edit:** Or you can use the [built-in memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1). In that case you don't have to use your cache helper as a singleton.

Comment: I tried singleton. But in that case I can't call SetCommonCacheItems.  Do you think that `MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());`  line is mistake? @PeterCsajtai

Comment: Why can't you call SetCommonCacheItems? That line which instantiates your own memory cache should work if your cachehelper is a singleton, if it remains scoped it'll be instantiated again and again for every new request. The other way is to replace that line with an injected IMemoryCache dependency provided by the framework.

Comment: I edited `CacheHelper.cs` with using adding dependency like that `CacheHelper: public CacheHelper(IMemoryCache cache, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {}` and I convert `startup.cs` like that `services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>());` It working now. I can get my cache value. But now only problem is for every request, running CacheHelper. But I want only when project starting and then for every 8 hour. How can I achieve this? @PéterCsajtai

Comment: What do you mean by running the CacheHelper? Loading the items from the repository into the cache? You can use timed background tasks via hosted services to achive something similar, check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more info

Comment: Yes. I mean like you said loading items  from repository to cache. I thougt that memory cache have option that refresh its data in every period(forexample 8 hour). I will try your suggested links. Thanks a lot.